# How to make mysqldump quit pulling the entire db when i command it to grab a single table?

Tags: mysql

Been working all day on this one.. when i request the table it gives me the entire data base..

```
#!/bin/bash
# mysqldump --user root --password=mypw sellnjho_realpro wp_posts >  atest.sql
mysqldump sellnjho_realpro wp_posts > atest.sql
echo "All Done."
```

Whether i add the table `wp_posts` or not it pulls the entire db 
I included the line with pw too in case that helps but the next line gives me the sql in full w/o the use of user or pw..

I tried user and pass to see and it failed all together telling me that using the user/pass on the command line was dangerous..

Comment: This is a question about the mysqldump command explicitly, not about shell in general (`mysqldump` is part of MySQL, not part of the shell); I'm updating the title and tags appropriately. BTW, what's with all the backticks? Did you add them as formatting, or are they really there in your actual script?

Comment: ...to be entirely explicit -- if they're part of your script, the backticks are *wrong*. For instance, ```$(echo "All done.")``` -- or the version with backticks in place of `$()` -- tries to run `All Done.` as a command, which fails for obvious reasons. And if they're part of your question's formatting, they're unnecessary -- the code formatting done by the `{}` button (or the four-space indents it creates) is sufficient.

Comment: Thanks for that but i was just copying the example they gave with the quotes not backtics.. and it seems to work fine and prints out done as it should thru out the program.. 
A little more detail.. when i use mysqldump and the dbname and table it does single out the table and exports that.. but when i try to add table to the import using mysql and no table it does put the table it exported into the correct table just fine.. so guess i am ok but thanks for the helping hand.

Comment: I'm a little clear about what you meant by your comment above, but if the output of `echo` is correctly printed, then clearly the backticks aren't **really** part of your code as you're running it, so I've edited them out of the question.

Answer (score 1):

For pulling data of a single table using `mysqldump` command, you can use following command -

```
mysqldump --user [username] --password [password] --host [hostname] --databases [db_name] --tables [table_name] --lock-tables > file.sql
```

In your case,

```
mysqldump --user root --password mypw --databases sellnjho_realpro --tables wp_posts --lock-tables > wp_posts.sql
```

Refer [this](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/mysqldump.html) link for more information on `mysqldump`